# $rootScope in AngularJS stays UNDEFINED in Controller despite injection?

Tags: angularjs, controller, ionic-framework, rootscope

It's a small ionic / angularJS project for a mobile app.

I am trying to read a JSON file in the same folder as index.html, then assigning it to a $rootScope variable in the RUN segment and then retrieving the $rootScope variable value in a controller. But it's simply not working despite service injections and all.

This is my JSON file:

```
    {"docs":[{"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany"},
             {"Name":"Ana Trujillin Moreo","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"}
            ]
    }
```

This is my app.js / script.js:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])    
    .run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $http) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        $rootScope.myDocs = $http.get("/customers.json")
                                 .success(function (response) {
                                    return response.docs;
                                  });
      });
    })

    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
      $scope.myDocs = $rootScope.myDocs;
      //$scope.myDocs = [{'Name': 'a1'},{'Name': 'b1'},{'Name': 'c1'}];
      $scope.myStr = JSON.stringify($rootScope.myDocs);
    }])
```

This is the relevant portion from my index.html:

```
<body ng-app="starter">    
      <ion-pane>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
          <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="x in myDocs">
        {{x.Name}}
        </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-pane>
</body>
```

I have seen other similar examples here but this is still not working and I been banging my head against the wall to achieve a very simple thing.

Fast help is much appreciated.
Here is the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/zx9ANUzCYVvosZFiPSGY?p=info

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be sure to check out the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour. If any answers solve your problem, mark the most helpful answer as "accepted" using the checkmark (it will turn green) to show your appreciation and to help future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

You're having a timing issue because of `ionicPlatform.ready` and you aren't using the `$http` promise correctly.

This is one way to do it:

```
.run(function($rootScope, $http) {
  // $http returns a promise, not the value
  $rootScope.docPromise = $http.get("/customers.json")
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.docs;
    });
})

.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  // you get the value within a .then function on the promise
  $rootScope.docPromise.then(function(result) {
    $scope.myDocs = result;
  })
}])
```

It is unlikely that you need to make this http call within `ionicPlatform.ready`. If you don't need to, then it is only delaying the call for no benefit. If for some reason you do need to make the call within the ready function, there are numerous ways to solve this. Here is one example:

```
// inject $q service
var deferred = $q.defer();
$rootScope.docPromise = deferred.promise;
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  $http.get(etc).then(function(response) {
    deferred.resolve(response.docs);
  });
});
// use $rootScope.docPromise as in the previous example
```

Comment: Exactly what I was about to write! +1 Additionally I would definitely consider using a router (ui-router) and resolves to load data for a specific view before the view will be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You might be assuming that the return value from the `success` method on `$http.get()` will be assigned to `myDocs` property on `$rootScope` but it doesn't work that way. `$http.get()` is an Asynchronous operation and the success callback will be invoked once the response is available. Also the return value from your success callback is not assigned because it happens sometime in the future.

You need to update your `ready()` like below.

```
   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
     /* get will return a promise, cache it in on rootScope for use in controller*/
      $rootScope.httpPromise = $http.get("/customers.json");
   });
```

**In your Controller**

```
   .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
      $rootScope.httpPromise.then(function(response){
           $scope.myDocs = response.data.docs;
       });
    }]);
```

Comment: The drawback of this is that you don't know when `$rootScope.myDocs` will be set. The OP may expect `console.log($rootScope.myDocs)` to have the value in his controller, but it won't.

Comment: @m59... Ya I understood the issue now. Even though I was caching response from http call in success callback, controller might be invoked even before call is complete which returns undefined again. Thanks for pointing that. I updated my answer to handle this :)

Comment: You still have the async issue with `$ionicPlatform.ready`. At the time the controller function is executed, `$rootScope.httpPromise` may not be assigned yet. My answer addresses this.